# Height 100% on css and bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have a doubt, the height 100 % is the total of the height of the div father? It is to say if I have a div of 100, and inside one of 20 % black and different 80 red %, if I put one of 100 % inside the red one, it will take 100 % as 80 % of the total?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz3X0.png)

If I do it, it takes 100 % as the total of the screen and father leaves of the div.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8B9x.png)

Thank you very much 4 time!

Comment: please show us your code, so we can take a look at it

Comment: please put your code so we can help you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

without your code its hard to help you because you can have some property who denied default comportment of elements but to reply to your question yes `height : 100%` take max height of the parent elements its need to be set on the parent in your first image if your html structur is good the div who take 100% will be take max heigth of 80% div but for exemple if you use float you lose the flux so you denied default parent heritage

Comment: Without the code, this is only a guess, so you should be voting to close, not answer it.

Comment: There is some way of making a navbar of bootstrap4 in pixels and of the remaining height do two divs that occupies each one 50% remaining height? [Image](https://imgur.com/a/LNw5oYL)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to divide the part inside of the red part to be 50/50 right?

As far as I can see it will take the percentage of the element that it was inside of. So the code should work and give you something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/dinhhuyanh99/tqrb6anw/

```
.container80 {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: rgb(20, 150, 20);
}

.container50 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  background-color: rgb(20, 150, 220);
}

.container20 {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(200, 15, 20);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without the code, this is only a guess, so you should be voting to close, not answer it.

Comment: Ty, there is some way of making a navbar of bootstrap4 in pixels and of the remaining height do two divs that occupies each one 50% remaining height? [Image](https://imgur.com/a/LNw5oYL)